# Error serving Angular page from node http server

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I'm using the following (server.js) to create a node http server to load an Angular page (index.html).

**server.js**

```
var http = require('http');
var fs   = require('fs');
var HOST = '127.0.0.1';
var PORT = 3000;

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {
      'Content-Type': 'text/html',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*'});
  response.end(fs.readFileSync('index.html'));
}).listen(PORT, HOST);
console.log('Node server listening at http://' + HOST + ':' + PORT);
```

**index.html**

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="planetApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Planet App</title>

    <!-- Include external styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />

    <!-- Include external Angular Libs -->
    <script src="js/lib/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lib/angular-route.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Include external custom JS files -->
    <script src="js/planetController.js"></script>
    <script src="js/planetFactory.js"></script>
    <script src="js/planetDirective.js"></script>
    <script src="js/planetApp.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-view></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The App loads fine if I serve it from WAMP, but I get the following error when I serve it from node:

```
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'
<html lang="en" ng-app="planetApp">
```

I think it may have something to do with the templateURL(s) in the following:

**planetApp.js**

```
var planetApp = angular.module('planetApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'planetController',
  'planetFactory',
  'planetDirective'
]);

// App Config - runs once to register controllers
planetApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.
    when('/', {
      templateUrl: '../templates/planet_list.html',
      controller: 'PlanetListCtrl'
    }).
    when('/:planetId', {
      templateUrl: '../templates/planet_detail.html',
      controller: 'PlanetDetailCtrl'
    }).
    otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/'
    });
});
```

Does anyone know how this can be resolved, using node's http server (not express)?

Thanks for any guidance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with the following:

**server.js**

```
var http = require('http');
var fs   = require('fs');
var HOST = '127.0.0.1';
var PORT = 3000;

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  var url = request.url;
  url = url.substring(1, url.length);
  response.writeHead(200, {
      'Content-Type': 'text/html',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*'});
  response.end(fs.readFileSync(url));
}).listen(PORT, HOST);
console.log('Node server listening at http://' + HOST + ':' + PORT);
```